# Is extending a string_view undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, string-view

Assume we have string s and a string_view sv on some part of s such that

```cpp
sv.data() + sv.size() < s.data() + s.size()
```

in other words, the character after the end of sv is still part of s. Is the following defined or undefined behavior?

```cpp
string_view sv1 {sv.data(), sv.size()+1};
```

So can we extend a string_view?

From cppreference:

> The behavior is undefined if [s, s+count) is not a valid range (even though the constructor may not access any of the elements of this range).

Is [sv.data(), sv.data() + sv.size() + 1) a valid range since it is part of s?

Comment: I don't see why it would not be undefined behavior, but couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: If the character that follows is actually a character, that you allocated. I see no problem except bad design.

Comment: Do note that when the standard says something is undefined behaviour, it allows anything to happen, even if there's an obvious defined way to do it. If the compiler sees you access `sv[i]`, it's allowed to assume `i` is less than `sv.size()` regardless of whether the underlying string is longer than the view. Once you give the compiler the freedom to make assumptions and optimize based on those assumptions, it becomes very dangerous to say "oh, the standard says this is UB but there's no way the compiler would emit code other than XYZ".

Comment: @chris This applies to `sv[i]` (because as you say the standard says so for `string_view::operator[]`), but I don't see any way that this applies to `sv.data() + i`, since `sv.data()` is just a pointer into the original string and forbidden this use of a `char*` specifically would be weird.

Comment: @uneven_mark, Then I'm curious why [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data) gives it an explicit valid range. Edit: Never mind, I think I read too much into it; the examples show null terminator use.

Comment: @chris I don't see any similar language in the standard's description of `data()` and cppreference is only saying that this range is valid, not that it is the maximal range to be valid. The choice of words "*and the values in it correspond to the values of the view*" also makes it sound as if it is returning a copy, which it isn't.

Comment: @uneven_mark It could be a problem if the standard does not specify that sv.data() points into s. If it just specifies, that sv has the same content as s in the range of sv, then there is no guarantee given on the character behind its end.

Comment: @n314159 In the standard the behavior is described through two exposition-only members `const charT* data_` and `size_t size_`. Construction is specified as simply copying the first argument to `data_` and the second to `size_`. `data()` is specified as just returning `data_`. An implementation can choose to implement this differently (exposition only members), but it must have the same observable behavior. So I think there is no ambiguity. Leaving this open would also kind of defeat the purpose of `string_view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming the following:

```
auto s = "The answer is: 42";
std::string_view sv{s, 5};
```

Then:

```
std::string_view sv1{sv.data(), sv.size() + 1};
```

Is a valid range. This totally goes against the C++ Core Guidelines and is likely not a great way to design your code... but yes... its valid.

Comment: If you make the `s` actually a `std::string`, it would be closer to OP's question (though your statement is true anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Extending `std::string_view`'s size is Undefined-Behavior.

**But** if you're creator of said `std::string_view`, hence know exactly how long the "viewed" `std::string` is, then you're just creating yet another `std::string_view`, and becasue `std::string_view::data()` returns always same as your input data, there's nothing undefined about that.